# How can I open folders in VS Code using Terminal with a fresh UI state?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code always opens a folder in with the last UI state.

I'm looking for something like Sublime's remember_open_files: false, or in other words, I would like VS Code to open with a clean UI state.

What's happening now:

```
cd my-project-folder/
code .
# VSCode opens folder with saved UI state`
```

What I want:

```
cd my-project-folder/
code .
# VSCode opens folder with fresh UI
```

Comment: The state is stored at the `.vscode` directory under the target directory. It's might not `code`'s problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to get what you want. I see related settings, but don't see one that does all of what you're looking for (I.e. not restoring open editors. Maybe I'm just missing it?)

- `window.restoreWindows`: Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first time. This setting has no effect when the application is already running.
- `workbench.editor.restoreViewState`: Restores the last editor view state (such as scroll position) when re-opening editors after they have been closed. Editor view state is stored per editor group and discarded when a group closes. Use the #workbench.editor.sharedViewState# setting to use the last known view state across all editor groups in case no previous view state was found for a editor group.
- `files.restoreUndoStack`: Restore the undo stack when a file is reopened.
- `window.restoreFullscreen`: Controls whether a window should restore to full screen mode if it was exited in full screen mode.
- `zenMode.restore`: Controls whether a window should restore to Zen Mode if it was exited in Zen Mode.
- `remote.restoreForwardedPorts`: Restores the ports you forwarded in a workspace.
- `interactiveWindow.restore`: Controls whether the Interactive Window sessions/history should be restored across window reloads. Whether the state of controllers used in Interactive Windows is persisted across window reloads are controlled by extensions contributing controllers.

That's all the settings I see with "restore" in their names. I think you might need to [create a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Possibly related issue ticket: [Restore open files from the previous session #171938](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171938)

Actually, there are feature requests about this:

- [Allow to open a workspace without restoring any state
  #22613](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22613) unfortunately closed as "out-of-scope", though someone shows a workaround for scripting deleting some SQLite bits of VS Code's state DB [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22613#issuecomment-997340969)
- ["Reset workspace" CLI option
  #147859](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147859) unfortunately closed pointing to the above as prior art.

If you don't want to open an existing folder with UI state, use the `-n` flag, which forces to open a new window.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.